# Solr Faceting - simple example complaining about asterisk

Tags: solr

I'm doing the most basic of solr queries with faceting.

```
q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=year
```

And I'm getting an error as follows:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*&facet=true&facet.field=year",
      "_": "1443134591151",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "undefined field *",
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

This query is straight out of the online tutorials. Why is solr complaining?

Comment: It looks like the special characters are taken as literals. Was this typed into a browser? What user agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that what you have done is gone to the Solr Admin panel and in the query section you have put

`*:*&facet=true&facet.field=year`

after the q. What you need to do is put *:* after the q, and facet=true&facet.field=year under Raw Query Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The error says, that you have "undefined field". Is "year" field defined in your schema? Also, can you give details about how you are querying the data. Like which client?And I assume that q=*:* is working and issue is only with faceting

Comment: But the error is `"msg": "undefined field *",` about `asterisk` not about `year` field.

Answer (score 0):

You've put it into the wrong line in the solr admin.
Just take the same line, and paste it into the Raw query line instead of the query line.